# how to hide logo in a specific section in html

Tags: html, css

[here's an image of my website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXhbu.png)
So i wanted to hide the logo when i'm in a specific section of my page

```
        <header class="header fixed">
          <div class="logo-header">
            <div class="box-img-flex">
              <img src="apecoinversebegins-1.png" alt="" />
            </div>
          </div>
      </header>
```

here is the code of my section how can i hide the logo in the header when I'm at about-section

```
<section class="section-full about-section" id="about-section">
    <div class="box-section">
      <div class="content-about animatedParent">
        <div class="box-info">
          <div class="box-title">
            <div class="box-effect animated">
              <img src="c34ec65089a85db8e48d.png" alt="" />
              <img src="8a050b0e8acee27315e0.png" alt="" />
              <img src="c8a7f7bc63b419a3ab10.png" alt="" />
              <img src="02239bf0005da23aa0a4.png" alt="" />
              <img src="0529e49ecbdae4ec396f.png" alt="" />
            </div>
        <div class="title animated">
          <img src ="apecoinversebegins-1.png" alt=""/>
          
          <!-- APECOINJr. <br />
          <p>ApeVerse</p> -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="desc" class="desc-theta animated fadeInUpShort delay-180"></div>
      <div class="total-player animated fadeInUpShort delay-500 mb-4" id="total-player"></div>
      <div id="download" class="box-download animated fadeInUpShort delay-300 mb-3"></div>
      <div id="contract-address" class="chain-table animated fadeInUpShort delay-400"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="box-mp4">
    <video playsinline autoplay muted loop id="bgvid">
      <source src="apevengers.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: do you mean hide it onscroll on the scpecific area of the page if so you can attain that using script.

Comment: @Crystal no sir the use of my header is that it toggle a specific section of the page so when i click home on the navbar it toggles the home section and in the home section I want to hide the logo of my website its because it's redundant

Comment: you mean onclick event on id="about-section" need to hide the image. First you need to tag jquery or javascript on your question because you can attain that on both ways. Let me put a sample for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a sample because I dont have all your code. Hope this will help you and let me know.

```js
//in Jquery this is how you hide it. 

$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#about-section").click(function(){
   $(".box-img-flex > img").toggle();// you can use .hide() also here
 });
 
  });



// in JavaScript

function myFunction() {
  var i = document.getElementById("box-img-flex");
  if (i.style.display === "none") {
    i.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    i.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<header class="header fixed">
          <div class="logo-header">
            <div class="box-img-flex">
              <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/27/c6/fb/27c6fb6dd18599fe89af78e314a8d6d8.png" alt="" />
            </div>
          </div>
      </header>


<section class="section-full about-section" id="about-section">
    <a href="#">CLICK ABOUT LINK TO HIDE</a>

  <div class="box-mp4">
    <video playsinline autoplay muted loop id="bgvid">
      <source src="apevengers.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
  </div>



<!--THIS IS ANOTHER EXAMPLE-->

<a href="#" onclick="myFunction()">CLICK ME AS ABOUT</a>

   <div class="box-img-flex" id="box-img-flex">
              <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/27/c6/fb/27c6fb6dd18599fe89af78e314a8d6d8.png" alt="" />
     </div>
```